# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow - how to get a user mail from list

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have got a list with emails. How can I get the emails in a SharePoint Designer workflow to send them an email asking that they approve a report. It should be eMails from the list, not from AD. I tried a lot of combination, but the email don't send to directors. Maybe it's why **i:0#.w|**

Here is a screen, what I tried:

[image]

Comment: I am not 100% sure of your question but you could place the field with the email into a variable and have the workflow email that person this way.